# Websphere Application Server 8.5.5 don't see imported client key

Tags: certificate, websphere, jax-ws, sign

I used this tutorial

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/tutorials/0905_griffith/

for setting up security for jax-ws web service on server side and now I want to call this web service via soapUI, I am signing message in soapUI, but after calling web service with this message I get error that server can't find signer key. What can be wrong? Binding is configured to contain trustore which contains keystore with client certificate.

StackTrace:

> CWWSS5514E: An exception while processing WS-Security message: com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.core.SoapSecurityException: CWWSS6521E: The Login failed because of an exception: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: CWWSS6810E: The runtime can not identify the key corresponding to the identifier [CN=klient,O=SD,C= PL:458001165]

```
at com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.core.SoapSecurityException.format(SoapSecurityException.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.wssapi.token.impl.CommonTokenConsumer.getSoapSecurityException(CommonTokenConsumer.java:586)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.wssapi.token.impl.CommonTokenConsumer.invoke(CommonTokenConsumer.java:426)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.wssapi.CommonContentConsumer.invokeTokenConsumer(CommonContentConsumer.java:679)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.wssapi.CommonContentConsumer.getKey(CommonContentConsumer.java:323)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.keyinfo.KeyInfoConsumer.getKey(KeyInfoConsumer.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.dsig.SignatureConsumer.callKeyInfoConsumer(SignatureConsumer.java:1140)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.dsig.SignatureConsumer.callKeyInfoConsumer(SignatureConsumer.java:1104)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.dsig.SignatureConsumer.invoke(SignatureConsumer.java:272)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.core.WSSConsumer.callSignatureConsumer(WSSConsumer.java:2924)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.core.WSSConsumer.callSignatureConsumer(WSSConsumer.java:2827)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.core.WSSConsumer.invoke(WSSConsumer.java:862)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.handler.WSSecurityConsumerBase.invoke(WSSecurityConsumerBase.java:110)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.handler.WSSecurityConsumerHandler._invoke(WSSecurityConsumerHandler.java:537)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.handler.WSSecurityConsumerHandler.access$100(WSSecurityConsumerHandler.java:127)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.handler.WSSecurityConsumerHandler$1.run(WSSecurityConsumerHandler.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.security.context.ContextImpl.runWith(ContextImpl.java:362)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.platform.websphere.auth.WSSContextImpl.runWith(WSSContextImpl.java:65)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.handler.WSSecurityConsumerHandler$2.run(WSSecurityConsumerHandler.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
at com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.handler.WSSecurityConsumerHandler.invoke(WSSecurityConsumerHandler.java:195)
at org.apache.axis2.handlers.AbstractHandler.invoke_stage2(AbstractHandler.java:133)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:343)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:360)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:195)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1583)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

Comment: Try to select <none> in SoapUI as Key identifier type. Or generate test app client to see if it works.

Comment: I am using SoapUI 4.5.2 and there is no option <None>, there are: Issuer Name and Serial Number (selected), Binary Security Token, X509 Certificate, Subject Key Identifier (none of them works). I thought about creating client in RAD, but my web service will be tested via SoapUI 4.5.2 so even if it would work via RAD client I would still have to make it work via SoapUI.

Comment: Ok, I have 3.5.1, I'll take a look later at 4.5, how it looks. But what will be a target client? Because it wont be soapUI at the end.

Comment: What happens if you use `Subject Key Identifier`? Could you please attach error message for that?

Comment: @Gas Target client will be some app working on Message Broker, I don't know much of a detail. With `Subject Key Identifier` error is the same, only identifier changes to "[v/+5ex4JMo5
lAY3cFPPpUnDcSOE=]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it's SoapUI issue and it is impossible to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, when I changed the 'Key Identifier Type ' to BinaryToken in SOAP UI 'Signature' pane, the server could understand and responded as expected. SOAP UI has a dropdown with various options for 'Key Identifier Type' and when 'BinaryToken' is selected, it means, consumer (SOAP UI here) will include it's certificate in the request itself and so server can extract it.